# ASP.NET Control Layout

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, layout

I'm a bit new to ASP.NET. Actually, I'm a marginalized VB/SQL programmer who is finally getting with the times. But, with new technology comes a new headache. Namely: Layout.

I cannot seem to get a freakin' ASP.NET page to look good. In design mode, I can insert a few tables, play with the justification, place controls and it looks all nice & neat until I hit F5. Then, I've got garbage in a browser. I do know some HTML, but trying to just make a simple form with a few (say, 15) controls look pretty seems quite impossible.

Tables grow/shrink/expand, they move all my stuff around the page and the inside walls sure adjust funny in design view. Controls I thought I'd centered no longer center, some stuff shifts to the right and other stuff shifts to the left. Frustrating to say the least!

So how, may I ask HOW does one design a nice interface in ASP.NET?

Do I need the assistance of a 3rd party WYSIWYG tool? Do I need a brain transplant? Do I need to forget about programming the rest of my life and settle for burger-flipping at the local fast-food joint?

Any help or tips or links or anything would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: +1 for this funny question, you made my day :) But sorry for not being helphul, i've go to bed now. All i can say is, read a lot about html and css and forget the VS Designer, i found it almost needless.

Comment: @Jason - +1 for being able to appreciate the difference between a web developer vs a web designer.

Comment: Post the code that you do have and perhaps ppl can give you some advice.

Comment: Configure VS to open in code view and you're halfway there.

Comment: @IrishChieftain hahaha, good stuff

Comment: Thanks, all, for appreciating the frustration developers go through. Nice to know once in a while there are others who also suffer the same pain :=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS designer is for MS to have something to talk about - in reality it's useless. You need to understand what's going on in the code and how html/css work.

Good place to start with is the css property: display. Every element has this property set(explicitly or implicitly) and it is the major player in the field. If you can understand that, the next important thing is about width/height, margin and padding. After that comes float and how it modifies everything. If you know those things then you can easily create html/css layouts.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to sound like much of an answer, but just my $0.02: Give [Asp.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) a try.  It is **much** easier to use and **much** more designer-friendly.  By "designer-friendly" I mean that it is fairly easy to use a program like [DreamWeaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) to do the actual design of the views, then mark it up with either [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) or use the standard Webforms markup -- while keeping the code completely separate.

For your consideration (both samples taken from Scott Guthrie's blog, linked above)...

#### Asp.Net Web Forms

```
<ul id="products">
    <% foreach(var p in products) { %>
        <li><%= p.Name %> ($<%= p.Price %>)</li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

#### Razor

```
<ul id="products">
    @foreach(var p in products) {
        <li>@p.Name ($@p.Price)</li>
    {
</ul>
```

As you can see, in the latter example, it would be fairly easy to add the templating after you (and/or a designer) has put together the design using a separate tool.

This fulfills your goal of "getting with the time" while easing you into design.  Honestly, the only WYSIWYG editors in the MS stack that I have ever used with some success are [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) and the designers for Visual Basic and WinForms.

Comment: IMO ASP.NET MVC is better suited for todays site development, because it doesn't make things a pain. It doesn't pretend that it's stateful, it does not create ids like ctl00$cph1$ctrlEmailAccountDetails$SaveButton and it doesn't have the infamous VIEWSTATE.

Answer (score 0):

this is interesting and i'd like to help out. ASP.NET content ultimately gets rendered as html (as i am sure you may well know), you can do right-click on your page and do a "view source" to see what gets rendered e.g if you had an asp.net gridview that would get rendered as an html table, you could search for the id of the asp.net gridview/html table and then use the id or if you specified a CssClass on the control, define your set of css to embelish or position your controls on your asp.net page.

Also, if you don't like the idea of "view source", if you are in Internet Explorer 7+, you can use the Developer Tools (in options) to know what is the html behind which control. In Firefox, you could install a plugin called "Firebug" and use that to know the html markup behind which asp.net control.

Hope the above helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really design web pages is to learn HTML and CSS. Period. DO NOT use WYSIWYG designers (like VS's designer, or Dreamweaver). If you're a programmer, you should be programming, not WYSIWYGing (at least for HTML).

Use the major browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari) to examine your layouts and make sure you get the layout you want. I HIGHLY recommend Firebug (a addon for FireFox) - it is EXTREMELY helpful because you can tinker with the styles and HTML until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes burger flipping is probably a preferred career choice when it comes to HTML and CSS.  Its horrible, vastly over complicated for what you want to achieve and takes up 90% of your time fiddling around with layout, aligning panels, images and text.  And it still won't look as good as a web designers site.
If you really want to save time try using MS MVC.  They have at least tried to hide the design stuff away from the developer to some extent but MVC is difficult to learn if you come from a Win form or traditional ASP.NET direction.

As for the advice on WYSIWYG designers, I disagree with the other contributors.  VS designer is not perfect but for an absolute beginner you have to start somewhere.  At least you can drag and drop controls onto a form and worry about the mark up and all the fiddly bits later - DONT use CSS to begin with - you will get frustrated and angry with it.  It is powerful in the right hands but for the rest of us who are developers not web designers its a painful and time consuming process.  Just get something that works although it will look awful.  Once you have something designed then you can apply CSS bit by bit while you build confidence.  Of course you could just give your mark up to a good web designer afterwards and let them deal with the task while you worry about code behind, business objects and data access.  This is the programmer part of things, not messing about with HTML and CSS.  The demise of Silverlight is a sad day for all as it had promise to stop all the time wasted fighting with CSS.

Firebug is OK until you look at your site in IE then it will all fall apart again.  I tend to use a combination of VS designer, IE Chrome and Firebug as they all have issues and problems.
The most important issue is MAKE SURE YOU INSTALL BROWSER SUPPORT INTO VISUAL STUDIO - especially if you want your site to look anything like you want it to in IE10 and the later Chrome and Firefox browsers.  You have some hope then of the stuff you designed in VS will at least position itself in the later browsers.